# why my image root not found

Tags: angularjs, go

i am using go-lang with angular to build a car view in this approach:
this is my main.go

```
router.GET("/shopping", carBaseController.CarsViewIndex)
router.GET("/images", galleryBaseController.GetImages)
```

in my controller\cars.go

```
    func (controller CarController) CarsViewIndex(c *gin.Context) {
        c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "carview.html", gin.H{
            "title": "Car Page"})
    }

func (controller GalleryController) GetImages(c *gin.Context)  {
    imageList := controller.galleryService.FindImages(&bson.M{})
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, &imageList)
    fmt.Println(imageList)
}
```

in my carview.html

```
                                    <div class="row mix-grid" ng-init="GetAllImages()" >
                                    <div class="col-md-3 mix photography" ng-repeat="image in allimages">
                                        <div class="hover-effect"  >
                                            <div class="img" ><img  src="imagesT/gallery/Thumb/{{image.imagename}}" alt=""
                                                                  class="img-responsive"/></div>
                                            <div class="info"><h3>Manage Images</h3><a href="#"
                                                                                               class="mix-link"><i
                                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></i></a><a
                                                    href="imagesT/gallery/{{image.imagename}}" data-lightbox="image-1"
                                                    data-title="Image 1" class="mix-zoom"><i
                                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></a></div>
                                        </div>
                                        this is the site fo cars
                                        <a class="btn btn-default" href="carinfo">Learn More
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
```

when i  enter http://localhost:3030/shopping every thing work fine but i found this error

```
    "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
http://localhost:3030/imagesT/gallery/Thumb/%7B%7Bimage.imagename%7D%7D"
```

i do not know why this error happen while every thing work fine and this what i fount with firbug :

```
<img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="imagesT/gallery/Thumb/2016-chevrolet-cruze-spied-completely-uncovered-news-car-and-driver-photo-658949-s-217x132.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `ng-src` instead of `src` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use **ng-src** instead of *src* in your **img** tag, you can resolve this issue.

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work
>   right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text
>   {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The
>   ngSrc directive solves this problem.

Check out the docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc).

Comment: What do you mean @tigerprogrammer ? It is the official angular site.. Anyway accept my answer please